# regex to match decimal numbers with comma as a separator

Tags: r, regex

As in title I need a regex in R that will match decimal numbers with comma as a separator in order to extract them from string with `stringr::str_extract` . Regex should catch the following cases:

```
0,1
10
1000,29
3,23313
```

I have tried something like this `[0-9]+,[0-9]+` but it didn't work

Comment: What have you tried? And what flavor regex is this?

Comment: try this one `\d+,\d+`

Comment: @BurnsBA I have edited a question with my attempt. I work in R

Comment: Please post the code. Are you using `gsub`? Use `regmatches` - `regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+(?:,\\d+)?", x))`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/AeWU0z).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+(?:,\\d+)?", x))
```

See this [R demo](https://ideone.com/AeWU0z).

To do the same with `stringr`, use [`stringr::str_extract_all`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/0.6.2/topics/str_extract_all) that *"extracts all pieces of a string that match a pattern"*:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "\\d+(?:,\\d+)?")
```

Note that `\d` in `stringr` functions may match all Unicode digits like

`0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᥏᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᭙᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᮹᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱉᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꣙꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꤉꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꩙０１２３４５６７８９`

So, probably you will be safer using

```
str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?")
```

Comment: In OP’s example there’s absolute nothing wrong with (a) using `str_extract`, or (b) `[0-9]` rather than `\\d` (although I also recommend the latter).

Comment: @KonradRudolph 1)`str_extract` only extracts a *single* (the first) occurrence of the pattern in the input, 2) `\d` in the TRE regex [only matches ASCII digits](https://ideone.com/iUeij4), it only matters for the `str_extract_all` since ICU regex flavor uses all shorthand character classes with the Unicode support by default.

Comment: Right, and all the cases OP listed consist of a single occurrence and it’s fairly likely that OP actually only wants to support ASCII digits since subsequent parsing  of Unicode digits would fail anyway: `as.numeric('1٥3')` = `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match one or more decimal numbers separated by commas:

```
\d+(?:,\d+)*
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is extracting whole numbers (no fractions), and don't care if you separator is a comma or anything else, you can use:

```
(\d+)
```

Comment: Not really, I need to extract whole decimal number from a string.

Comment: Can you provide expected results to the examples you gave?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it matches numbers, optionally followed by a comma and one or more digits:

```
\b\d+(,d+)?\b
```